# How do you correctly add a CSS class to a react component (with broken example)?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have just started a React app from a tutorial and have been carefully following it. However very early on I see that a class that I believe I am correctly importing from a CSS file is not showing up in the output. I am expecting a 16 pixel margin in the element with the 'main' tag. The CSS file is called Layout.css and is in the same directory as the JavaScript file (Layout.js) that uses it. There is only one class in the CSS file, Content, and when I run the app I don't see the style (16 px margin) on the page and examining the page in the tools (chrome dev tools) I don't see the style under the styles tab. Here is the CSS file (src/components/Layout/Layout.css):

```
.Content {
    margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Here is the JS file (src/comonents/Layout/Layout.js):

```
import React from 'react';

import Auxi from '../../hoc/Auxi';
import classes from './Layout.css'

const layout = (props) => (
    <Auxi>
        <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
        <main className={classes.Content}>
            {props.children}
        </main>
    </Auxi>
);

export default layout;
```

I don't think it's part of the problem, but here are the other three JS files in the app for completeness.
src/App.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import Layout from './components/Layout/Layout';
import BurgerBuilder from './containers/BurgerBuilder/BurgerBuilder';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <BurgerBuilder />
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

src/hoc/Auxi.js:

```
const auxi = (props) => props.children;

export default auxi;
```

src/containers/BurgerBuilder.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Auxi from '../../hoc/Auxi';

class BurgerBuilder extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Auxi>
                <div>Burger</div>
                <div>Build Controls</div>
            </Auxi>
        );
    }
}

export default BurgerBuilder;
```

For additional completeness here is the src directory structure:

[image]

And here's what I see on the Chrome browser when I run it:
[image: Picture of Chrome browser]

So to recap: I have attempted to use a CSS file in a React app with one class. When attempting to use the class I do not see the style and am unsure why. Could anyone provide some insight?

Comment: import './layout.css', and className='content'

Comment: You're trying to use className={classes.Content} which will only work if you have modified your webpack config, I believe from memory it might be CSS Modules but has been a while since I used it. 
If you have no memory of changing anything in your webpack then you need to use className="content" and import your stylesheet as outlined above by SamwellTarly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your issue is but the code looks somehow off.

Make the changes as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import Auxi from '../../hoc/Auxi';
// *** change here ***
import from './Layout.css'

const layout = (props) => (
    <Auxi>
        <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>

        // *** change here ***
        <main className="Content">
            {props.children}
        </main>
    </Auxi>
);

export default layout;'
```

See the comments `// *** change here ***` for the lines I changed.

Comment: @op This is the right way. Also don't forget to follow naming conventions. camelCase for files and kebab-case for css classes

Comment: @SamwellTarly Right, I just followed the class naming in the current file.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that you all SamwellTarly and Oliver Heward and  Shmili Breuer that did it. I can now continue. Thanks!